# Tensorflow lite error! ValueError:Cannot set tensor: Got value of type NOTYPE but expected type FLOAT32 for input 0, name: lstm_input

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

hi I have built a model a now I want to deploy it on TensorFlow lite

the problem is that I can inference the model before moving one to the android application

the code is below

```
#Generate a SavedModel

export_dir = 'saved_model/1'
tf.saved_model.save(model, export_dir)

#CONVERT

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(export_dir)
#converter.optimizations = [optimization]
tflite_model = converter.convert()

#SAVE

tflite_model_file = pathlib.Path('model.tflite')
tflite_model_file.write_bytes(tflite_model)

# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors
#allocating the tensors for the model via the interpreter's allocate tensors function

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

#extract the inputs and outputs tensors of the model to begin testing.

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details() 
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

print (input_details)
[{'name': 'lstm_input', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([  1, 100,   6]), 'shape_signature': array([  1, 
100,   6]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': 
{'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 
0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]

print (output_details)
[{'name': 'Identity', 'index': 83, 'shape': array([], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([], 
dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': 
{'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 
0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]

#fill the current input tensor with some valid data
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], X_test)

#invoke the interpreter to run the model
interpreter.invoke()

#get the results produced by our TF Lite model by getting the output sensor.
tflite_results= interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
```

ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Got value of type NOTYPE but expected type FLOAT32 for input 0, name: lstm_input

is the problem due to 0 index in input_details?